# i'd like to output json_encode array into javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

if my json_encode outputs like this.

```
[{"id":"nameid","src":"http#"},{"id":"nameid","src":"http#"}]
```

how can i turn into something like:

```
[["name1","address1"],["name2","address2"]]
```

Comment: Aside from being an array with two members, the two data structures appear to have nothing in common, so there is no logical way to perform a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj, result, source, _i, _len;
  source = [
    {
      "id": "nameid",
      "src": "http#"
    }, {
      "id": "nameid",
      "src": "http#"
    }
  ];
  result = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = source.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    obj = source[_i];
    result.push([obj.id, obj.src]);
  }
```

(That was generated by coffeescript.  The coffeescript source FYI is much smaller)

```
source = [{"id":"nameid","src":"http#"},{"id":"nameid","src":"http#"}]
result = []
result.push([obj.id, obj.src]) for obj in source
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that `name1` is the value `nameid` from the first object, etc...

Convert it to the array format you want before passing it to `json_encode()`.  Something like this might work for you:

```
// Assuming your objects are an array $objects
$output_array = array();
foreach ($objects as $o) {
  // Put the two properties from the object into an array
  // and append it to $output_array
  $output_array[] = array($o->id, $o->src);
}

// Encode the array as json
$json = json_encode($output_array);
```